# How do I prevent transitive dependencies from a test-scoped dependency from getting packaged in my WAR in Maven?

Tags: maven, maven-3, transitive-dependency

I’m using Maven 3.2.3.  In my pom I have this test dependency

```
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.mainco.subco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
                    <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
                    <type>test-jar</type>
                    <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
```

However, I notice that Maven is bringing in JAR files that the test-jar is dependent on as compile time.  Below is an excerpt from
mvn dependency:tree …

```
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.9.5:test
[INFO] \- org.mainco.subco:core:test-jar:tests:80.0.0-SNAPSHOT:test
[INFO]    +- org.mainco.subco:session:jar:80.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons-core:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.1:runtime
[INFO]    |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.4:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.3.2:compile
[INFO]    |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:jar:1.8.5:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.8.1:compile (version selected from constraint [2.2,))
```

How can I suppress Maven from compiling dependencies into my WAR if they were included from a test-scoped dependency?

**Edit** Per the comment, below is the copmlete output from mvn depdency:tree

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ myproject ---
[INFO] org.mainco.subco:myproject:war:80.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.directwebremoting:dwr:jar:3.0.0-rc2:compile
[INFO] +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4:provided
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:provided
[INFO] +- org.mainco.subco:database:jar:80.0.0-SNAPSHOT:test
[INFO] +- org.mainco.subco:orders:jar:80.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- quickbase:quickbase:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mainco.subco.sf:enterprise:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mainco.subco.sf:metadata:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mainco.subco.sf:partner:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.salesforce:force-wsc-uber:jar:33.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mainco.subco:core:jar:80.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.itextpdf:itextpdf:jar:5.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:jar:138:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:jar:138:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.bouncycastle:bctsp-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:3.2.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:1.8.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.2.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.2.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.2.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.6.3:provided
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.2.11.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.2.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:    3.1.4.RELEASE:compile   
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- taglibs:standard:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.22:test
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.3:provided
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.3:provided
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.2:provided
[INFO] |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:jar:1.46:provided
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.9.5:test
[INFO] \- org.mainco.subco:core:test-jar:tests:80.0.0-SNAPSHOT:test
[INFO]    +- org.mainco.subco:session:jar:80.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons-core:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.1:runtime
[INFO]    |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.4:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.3.2:compile
[INFO]    |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:jar:1.8.5:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.8.1:compile (version selected from constraint [2.2,))
[INFO]    +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO]    +- spy:spymemcached:jar:2.8.4:compile
[INFO]    +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO]    +- org.jasypt:jasypt:jar:1.9.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.jasypt:jasypt-springsecurity3:jar:1.9.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.jasypt:jasypt-hibernate4:jar:1.9.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.0.CR2:compile
[INFO]    +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.6.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.6.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO]    +- org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:jar:4.3.6.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  \- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:2.4.3:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.2.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- eu.bitwalker:UserAgentUtils:jar:1.15:compile
[INFO]    +- net.jeremybrooks:knicker:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO]    +- net.java.dev.jets3t:jets3t:jar:0.9.0:compile
[INFO]    |  \- com.jamesmurty.utils:java-xmlbuilder:jar:0.4:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.9:compile
[INFO]    +- net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:jar:jdk15:2.4:compile
[INFO]    |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO]    |  \- net.sf.ezmorph:ezmorph:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO]    +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.2:compile
[INFO]    +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.2:compile
[INFO]    +- org.owasp.esapi:esapi:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO]    |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- xom:xom:jar:1.2.5:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.beanshell:bsh-core:jar:2.0b4:compile
[INFO]    \- org.owasp.antisamy:antisamy:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO]       +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-css:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO]       |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-ext:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO]       |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-util:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO]       |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis-ext:jar:1.3.04:compile
[INFO]       +- net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:jar:1.9.16:compile
[INFO]       \- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Check your pom's cause the dependencies could come from everywhere you project. Furthermore a reference to `${project.parent.version}` should be changed to `${project.version}`...Apart from that without the full dependency tree output and which artifacts are becoming part of your war which you don't like to have or which you assume are wrong it's impossible to help.

Comment: Keeping the discussion focussed on the dependency question, I have included the complete output from mvn dependency:tree .

Comment: I would presume you have a `dependencyManagement` section in which you explicitly configured the scope of other dependencies as compile, which overrides the scope of any transitive dependencies. Don't use scopes in your dependencyManagement blocks (and *never* the compile scope), scopes should only be defined in the actual dependency block.